# How do I rotate a tikz rectangle about a specific axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, rotating

I am trying to create a beamer animation using tikz, but I can't even get basic rotating of a tikz image working as desired.

I have a rectangle specified by

```
\draw[rounded corners,dotted] (-3.5,0) rectangle (-0.5,2);
```

I would like to rotate this rectangle about the point (-1,.5) (which is near the bottom right corner of the rectangle).  I've tried:

```
{\rotatebox[origin=c,x=-1,y=.5]{130}{
            \draw[rounded corners,dotted] (-3.5,0) rectangle (-0.5,2);}}
```

But this produces an error.  If I just use the `origin=c` option, it compiles, but it rotates the rectangle about the point (0,0).  I've also tried it with just the `x=-1,y=.5` (without the origin option), and it fails to compile.

I have searched the documentation, which is where I learned about the options `x=xdim` and `y=ydim`.  However, I can't find a single example demonstrating how these options should be used.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Also, if there is a better command for rotating things that will be more suitable for use in a beamer animation, please let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

TikZ has a `rotate around={<angle>:<coordinate>}` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (-1,0.5) circle [radius=2pt];
\draw[rounded corners] (-3.5,0) rectangle (-0.5,2);
\draw[rounded corners,red,rotate around={30:(-1,0.5)}] (-3.5,0) rectangle (-0.5,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes it is definitely the right way, even without `rotate around`  it is possible but more complicated to obtain the same result but I think it should be avoided in most cases, `rotatebox`, `resizebox` etc.

Comment: +1 As usual, a brilliant answer. I notice that you usually use the `standalone` documentclass for demonstrating pictures- is this a convention that you adopt when producing documents too?