# Polaroid photo effect in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics

Is there any way to make a polaroid  photo effect in TikZ?  I am thinking of something like this [image]

A computer font as the caption might be better in fact but I couldn't find a suitable example online.

I think what is needed is a nice shadow effect outer box, the image placed inside it, a way to do the caption suitably and then for the whole thing to be rotated. I found a few related looking answer but I have no idea how to put them together or if they are suitable. For example,  [Translate and rotate an object in TikZ (2D)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/translate-and-rotate-an-object-in-tikz-2d) and [Faded drop-shadow using tikz-based rounded rectangle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11272/faded-drop-shadow-using-tikz-based-rounded-rectangle) .

My beginning attempt doesn't use TikZ at all and is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begin{adjustbox}{addcode={\begin{minipage}{\width}}{\caption*{%
      \tiny{Hello world!}
      }\end{minipage}},rotate=-5,center}
      \includegraphics[width=2cm]{face}%
  \end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This gives

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Oh! Aishwarya Rai in TeX.SX. :-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks. You are right. I have never used TikZ except by copy and pasting to be honest but I will do my best.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Edit (2016/05/27): Improved version at the end -- cleaner box style, usage of `xparse`.

Something like this

Description: I defined a command `\polaroid`, taking five arguments, the first being optional, designed for the `tcolorbox` only.

- 1st arg: `tcolorbox` settings
- 2nd arg: Rotation angle in degrees
- 3rd arg: Scaling of the image
- 4th arg: Image file name
- 5th arg: Caption

---

The shadow is blurred now, the detailed settings depend on the personal request and can not be done here, change the `fuzzy shadow` option values at will.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{article}%

\usepackage{tcolorbox}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%

\tcbuselibrary{skins}%

\begin{document}%

\newcommand{\polaroid}[5][top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,boxsep=0pt,colback=white,width=8cm,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,fuzzy shadow={2mm}{-2mm}{1mm}{0.3mm}{black}]{%
\tcbset{enhanced}
\rotatebox{#2}{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[#1]
  \begin{center}%
   \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2pt}%
   \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
   \fbox{%
    \includegraphics[scale=#3]{#4}}

    #5%
  \end{center}%
\end{tcolorbox}%
}%
}%


\polaroid{-10}{0.25}{face}{\Large \textsf{\textbf{Hello World!}}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Old version**

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%

\begin{document}%

\rotatebox{10}{\begin{tcolorbox}[width=8cm]%[shadow={2mm}{-1mm}{0mm}{black!50!white}]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{bild_erwin_schroedinger}

\Huge Hello World%
\end{center}
\end{tcolorbox}
}%


\end{document}
```

[image]

About the jaggy lines issue: Adding a tight `\fbox` around the image overprints the lines, but it is only a work around.

[image]

Admitted, Erwin Schrödinger is not as sexy as that actress ;-)

**Update** A better version, with `tikz` styles and special settings:

Another version of the `\polaroid` command, this time with `xparse`:

- 1st arg optional: `tcolorbox` settings
- 2nd arg: file name
- 3rd arg optional : Scaling of the image
- 4th arg: caption
- 5th arg optional : rotation angle

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}%

\tcbset{%
  polaroid/.style={%
    enhanced,
    top=1cm,
    left=1cm,
    right=1cm,
    bottom=1cm,
    boxsep=0pt,
    colback=white,
    width=8cm,
    sharp corners,
    lower separated=false,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    halign lower=center,
    fuzzy shadow={2mm}{-2mm}{1mm}{0.3mm}{black}
  },%
  polaroidframe/.style={%
    size=tight,
    boxrule=2pt,
    colframe=black,
  }%
}


\newtcolorbox{polaroidbox}[1][]{%
  polaroid,
  #1
}

\newtcbox{polaroidframe}[1][]{%
  polaroidframe,
  #1
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\polaroid}{O{}mO{0.25}+mO{-10}}{%
\rotatebox{#5}{%
  \begin{polaroidbox}[#1]
    \polaroidframe{\includegraphics[scale=#3]{#2}}
    \tcblower
    #4
  \end{polaroidbox}%
}
}

\begin{document}%

\polaroid{face}[0.2]{\Large\bfseries \sffamily Hello World}[180]
\polaroid{face}[0.2]{\Large\bfseries \sffamily Hello World}[0]
\polaroid{face}[0.2]{\Large\bfseries \sffamily Hello World}[90]
\polaroid{face}[0.2]{\Large\bfseries \sffamily Hello World}[270]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You made a mistake. There are not enough stars to spell brainy.

Comment: Erwin is very aishwary in that foto though

Comment: @eleanora: I meant sexy, not brainy :D :D

Comment: @eleanora: The only jaggy part is the image itself, since it's a non-vector graphic format (*.jpg), the `tcolorbox` and its shadow is not jaggy at all, since they are using vector graphics commands. I can't do anything against jaggy formats as is

Comment: OK thanks. Maybe someone knows a workaround/clever fix.  (The transparent border trick doesn't seem to work. I just added a border from the command line with convert -background none -gravity Center -extent 602x689 face.jpg face2.png and it didn't help.)

Comment: @eleanora: I added a small `\fbox` around the image automatically, reducing the jaggy effect.

Comment: Thanks. I can't get your code to work. I get   Runaway argument?
{\begin {tcolorbox}[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,boxsep=0pt,\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \Grot@box@std was complete.

Comment: @eleanora: I'll check immediately

Comment: @eleanora: Sorry, I don't get any error message: Do you have the lastest TeXLive (2014)? (I had my weekly update yesterday). The code provides the desired output, but I have to update the screenshot, however

Comment: I am using texlive 2013. I can't upgrade at the moment.

Comment: Can anyone get this solution to work in texlive 2013 ? (Or anything before texlive 2014.)

Comment: I think everyone understands it's a joke :)

Comment: percusse fixed it for me. You need to remove the empty line before #5 .

Comment: @eleanora: The empty line was there on purpose, to provide some space between the figure and the caption!

Comment: Ah.. well it seems it kills texlive 2013 sadly.

Comment: @eleanora: Perhaps its only tcolorbox which has to updated. Current version is 3.12

Comment: Could be. Mine is 2.70.  In any case removing the empty line fixes it for me.

Answer (score 23):

Here is a flexible and customizable solution usable into a tikzpicture.

Description of keys:

- `at` defines the center of the picture,
- `graphics options` defines the options used by `\includegraphics`,
- `rotate` defines the global rotation of the polaroid,
- `caption` define the content of the caption,
- `caption distance` defines the distance between the top of caption and the bottom of the picture,
- `top margin`, `bottom margin`, `left margin`, `right margin`, `vmargin`, `hmargin` and `margin` are used to define the margins between the picture and the borders of the polaroid,
- `caption option` defines the options used by the caption node,
- `frame options` defines the options used by the frame node (the whole polaroid).

Each key has a default value. The optional argument of `\polaroid` macro is used to change these value for a particular polaroid. You may use `\polaroidset` to change the default values for all subsequent polaroids in the current group.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}%
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,shadows,backgrounds,positioning}
\tikzset{
  polaroid/.cd,
  at/.store in=\polaroidat,
  at={0,0},
  graphics options/.store in=\polaroidgraphicsoptions,
  graphics options=,
  rotate/.store in=\polaroidrotate,
  rotate=0,
  caption/.store in=\polaroidcaption,
  caption=,
  caption distance/.store in=\polaroidcaptiondistance,
  caption distance=1mm,
  top margin/.store in=\polaroidtopmargin,
  bottom margin/.store in=\polaroidbottommargin,
  left margin/.store in=\polaroidleftmargin,
  right margin/.store in=\polaroidrightmargin,
  vmargin/.style={top margin=#1,bottom margin=#1},
  hmargin/.style={left margin=#1,right margin=#1},
  margin/.style={vmargin=#1,hmargin=#1},
  margin=1cm,
  caption default/.style={font=\bfseries,node distance=1mm},
  caption options/.style={caption default/.append style={#1}},
  frame default/.style={draw,inner sep=0},
  frame options/.style={frame default/.append style={#1}},
}
\newcommand\polaroidset[1]{\tikzset{polaroid/.cd,#1}}
\newcommand\polaroid[2][]{
  \bgroup
  \tikzset{polaroid/.cd,#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\polaroidrotate{\polaroidrotate}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(\polaroidat)},rotate=\polaroidrotate]
    \node[rotate=\polaroidrotate,inner sep=0]
    (shoot) {\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\polaroidgraphicsoptions]{#2}};
    \path (shoot.north) ++(0,\polaroidtopmargin) coordinate (polaroid top);
    \path (shoot.south) ++(0,{-1*(\polaroidbottommargin)}) coordinate (polaroid bottom);
    \path (shoot.west) ++({-1*(\polaroidleftmargin)},0) coordinate (polaroid left);
    \path (shoot.east) ++(\polaroidrightmargin,0) coordinate (polaroid right);
    \node[rotate fit=\polaroidrotate,fit=(polaroid top)(polaroid bottom)(polaroid left)(polaroid right),polaroid/frame default]{};
    \node[rotate=\polaroidrotate,inner sep=0]
    (shoot) {\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\polaroidgraphicsoptions]{#2}};
    \coordinate (caption center) at ($(shoot.south)!-1 * \polaroidcaptiondistance!(shoot.north)$);
    \node[anchor=north,rotate=\polaroidrotate,polaroid/caption default]
    (caption) at (caption center) {\polaroidcaption};
  \end{scope}
  \egroup
}

\begin{document}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \polaroid[rotate=-10,
  frame options={line width=1pt,draw,rounded corners=.5mm,fill=white,drop shadow},
  graphics options={width=4cm}]
  {face}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \polaroidset{
    rotate=20,
    frame options={line width=1pt,draw=cyan,rounded corners=.5mm,fill=cyan!10,drop shadow},
    graphics options={width=2.5cm},
    caption options={font=\footnotesize,align=center},
    caption distance=.5mm,
    vmargin=5mm,hmargin=5mm,
    bottom margin=5mm+1em,
  }
  \foreach \i in {0,...,6}{
    \polaroid[rotate={90-\i*30},at={{90-\i*30+90}:5cm},caption=Hello\\World]{face}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is really great. Thank you. I notice that you (and others) have really made an attractive picture frame not a polaroid. The dimensions in a polaroid are different as are the margins.  That is narrow margins at the top and side and the overall frame is not square. Of course with your lovely flexible solution this is easy to fix.

Answer (score 19):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180442/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc, shadows, shadows.blur}

\newcommand\addcurlyshadow[2][]{
    % #1: Optional aditional tikz options
    % #2: Name of the node to "decorate"
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \rotatebox{10}{%
            \path[blur shadow={shadow xshift=0pt, shadow yshift=0pt, shadow blur steps=6}, #1]
            ($(#2.north west)+(.3ex,-.5ex)$)
            -- ($(#2.south west)+(.5ex,-.7ex)$)
            .. controls ($(#2.south)!.3!(#2.south west)$) .. (#2.south)
            .. controls ($(#2.south)!.3!(#2.south east)$) .. ($(#2.south east)+(-.5ex,-.7ex)$)
            -- ($(#2.north east)+(-.3ex, -.5ex)$)
            -- cycle;
        }
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}

        \begin{tikzpicture}

        \rotatebox{10}{%

            \node[draw=black!40, fill=white, rectangle, minimum width=4.5cm, minimum height=4.5cm]
            (example) {
                \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2pt}%
                \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
                \fbox{%
                    \includegraphics{example-grid-100x100bp.pdf}%
                }%
            };
            \addcurlyshadow{example}
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very nice shadow!

Answer (score 5):

For fun, here is a solution in ConTeXt. The solution relies on [my wrapper](https://github.com/adityam/dropshadow) around the [drops](https://spideroak.com/browse/share/indiego/public/ConTeXt/drops/) module by Peter Rolf. The drops module uses imagemagic to draw the shadow (which looks more realistic than the tikz-style shadows)

```
\usemodule[dropshadow]
\setupexternalfigures[location={local,global,default}]

\definedropshadow
      [polaroid]
      [flatdark]
      [
        frame=on,
        rulethickness=8bp,
        framecolor=white,
        backgroundcolor=white,
        offset=10bp,
        strut=no,
        boffset=30pt,
      ]


\starttext
\rotate[rotation=10]{\usedropshadow{polaroid}{\externalfigure[mill][frame=on]}}
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]