# Smooth shadow of figure in beamer

Tags: beamer, floats, shadows

I want to add a shadow to some figures in my `beamer` presentation. So far I have found the `fancybox` package. However, its `\shadowbox{}` looks quite old-fashioned:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \shadowbox{\includegraphics[width= 0.8\textheight]{pic/test.jpg}}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: fancybox shadowbox]

I am wondering if there is any possibility to create smoother shadows with `beamer` as they can be created in Powerpoint like this:

[image: smoother shadow example from powerpoint]

Comment: With `tikz` you can do all kind of fancy shadows, see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195083/polaroid-photo-effect-in-tikz/195099#195099

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package `tcolorbox` has option `beamer` for boxes with shadows for use in in cases as it is yours:

[image]

Image is in `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\centering
\begin{tcolorbox}[beamer,
                  width=0.8\textheight,
                  arc=0pt,
                  boxsep=0pt,
                  left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
                  ]
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```