# Which package for drawing 3D robot arms

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, packages, 3d, sketch

I want to start a guide for explaining the theory behind industrial robot arms, like this one:

[image]

I want to create some command for drawing a 3D schema of the robot arm. My commands should:

- Store in a variable the robot parameters (like number of arms and their length);
- Store in a variable the kinematic state (angles of joints);
- Have a command for drawing the arm using the previous two variables as argument.
- Draw some data in the figure, like a formula near a joint.

At the end I'd like to have commands for easily drawing something like that:

[image]

I don't want that you creates these commands for me, it should be my effort and I have to try something by myself at first, of course...

Instead I'd like to know which packages I have to study in order to create a custom package with commands that I need. I know a bit TikZ, but [I've read somewhere](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/three-link-annotated/#c426) that's not very well suited for this kind of work. I've read about Asymptote, that I know but I've never used, as well as [Sketch](http://sketch4latex.sourceforge.net/sketch.pdf).

Do you suggest one of these two, or you have some other package in mind that it's more suited for my needs?

EDIT:

I don't think that's a duplicate question, because it's not regarded on how draw something general. My question is very specific on about drawing a schema of a 3D robot by creating a specific command, so the package must be able to draw 3d shapes and it should be possible to do it in a parametric way.

Comment: Don't do that in TeX. Go for your 3D program of choice, make a nice arm with all the functionality you need, export a picture, put it into TeX with annotations there. Easier, cleaner, faster. It is technically possible to do your idea in TikZ but it is a pain. If you insist on Tikz, here is a starter on 3D coordinate systems: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375604/132800

Comment: Even after editing your post is very broad. We could help you if you started with some code in any of those packages to draw something specific you've got a problem with, but which package to choose, is mostly a matter of preference. As Huang_d already mentioned, it would also be a wise option not to use LaTeX to draw it at all.

Comment: If it is not a duplicate it would be too broad.

Comment: I also needed to show my mechanical arm simulation in Solidworks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crJXUlzJ918